# Необходимо ли определять ядро для исполнения потока?

Tags: php, многопоточность

Использую потоки (от 0 до 100) и мне стало интересно, есть ли возможность определять ядро на котором поток будет исполняться? Если есть, то необходимо ли вообще это? Можно ли просто запустить 100 потоков?

Comment: Простой поток будет прыгать между ядрами. В linux можно определить его "мгновенную" локацию, через `rdtscp`. Сомневаюсь, что в `PHP` есть доступ к `rdtscp`. Но даже если его организовать, **что Вам даст это знание?**

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, реализовано ли это в php, а в принципе (по крайней мере, если говорить о `pthreads` в Linux) все это возможно.

Почитайте:

- [man pthreads](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html)
- [man sched_setaffinity](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity)
- [man pthread_setaffinity_np](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_setaffinity_np)
- и SEE ALSO к ним.

Необходимо ли задавать ядра? Не думаю, что это может быть актуально для решаемых в ПХП задач.